# Transform affect autoresizemask uiimageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, transform

I'm working on an iOS photo app and I have met some problems.

I have a main UIImageView with multiple image subviews, all subviews have autoresizingMask ON.
I can rotate, scale any subviews from main imageView and then I want to save an image from main UIImageView with all it's subviews.

There is the code that I use:

```
CGRect temp = editedImage.frame;
CGRect temp2 = editedImage.frame;
temp2.size = editedImage.image.size;
editedImage.frame = temp2;
editedImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(editedImage.frame.size);
[editedImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

editedImage.frame = temp;
```

editedImage - is the main UIImageView with many subviews.

**Problem:** If I rotate a subview from editedImage and after execute the code above then my subview becomes smaller, and each time I do that it becomes smaller and smaller.

Could someone give me an advice why this happens or to give some suggestions how I can solve this?